# Pandas reading int elements of mixed float/int type column as nans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Initially I was having problems with my data because of extra commas at the end of the csv, but I used a script to remove those. Now I have the title Issue. Here's where the issue starts with one of my data sets. I illustrate a portion of one dataset.

```
3474,6951,2011-10-22,4,0,10,5,0,6,0,1,0.38,0.3939,0.66,0.0,1,7,361.0  
3475,6952,2011-10-22,4,0,10,6,0,6,0,1,0.36,0.3788,0.71,0.0,1,17,383.0  
 3476,6953,2011-10-22,4,0,10,7,0,6,0,1,0.36,0.3636,0.76,0.1045,8,49  
3477,6954,2011-10-22,4,0,10,8,0,6,0,1,0.4,0.4091,0.71,0.0,26,88
```

the final column is supposed to be my target column for regression. When pandas reads the whole dataframe, it interprets elements of that column from index 1 through 3475 perfectly as floats. Eg. df[target][3475] = 383.0. However, df[target][i] for i > 3475 is listed as nan.

I have tried forcing the column to be float type, but have not had any success. 
I should also note that I have other data sets with the same problem. One of them is such that ALL of the target elements are ints. In this case pandas interprets all of the target elements as nan.

The code I'm using to load these data is:

```
df_train = pd.read_csv(dataset+str("_train")+str(fold)+".csv").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might come as surprise, your cvs file has inconsistent # of fields.

With this command, index starts from 1
`cat int_float.csv |cut -d"," -f16,17,18`

```
1,7,361.0 
1,17,383.0  
8,49
26,88
```

Which is consistent with `pd.read_csv`

```
       14  15  16       17  
0     0.0   1   7   361.0   
1     0.0   1  17  383.0    
2  0.1045   8  49      NaN  
3     0.0  26  88      NaN
```